# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, (but not obvious where headers are being re-set)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error after I: 1. sign-in, 2. log-out, and then 3. log-in.

My confusion results from: 1. I don't even see where the code is setting headers in the `'login'` `post` route, and 2. The sequence of commands in the `'/login'` `post` route where the error seems to be occurring is the same as in the `'/signup'` `post` route, and the latter executes with no problems. i.e., both have assignments to `req.session.user`, followed by `res.redirect('/protected_page');`

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: "Shh, it's a secret!"}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

var users = [];

app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('signup');
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.id || !req.body.password) {
        res.status(400);
        res.send("Invalid details!");
    } else {
        users.filter(function(user) {
            if (user.id === req.body.id) {
                res.render('signup', {
                    message: "User Already Exists! Login or choose another user id"});
            } 
        });
    var newUser = {id: req.body.id, password: req.body.password};
    users.push(newUser);
    req.session.user = newUser;
    res.redirect('/protected_page');
    }
});

function checkSignIn(req,res, next){
    if (req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        var err = new Error("Not logged in!");
        next(err);
    }
}

app.get('/protected_page', checkSignIn, function(req, res){
    res.render('protected_page',{id: req.session.user.id});
})

app.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login');
})

app.post('/login', function(req,res){
    if (!req.body.id || !req.body.password) {
        res.render('login', {message: "Please enter both id and password!"});
    } else {
        users.filter(function(user){
            if (user.id === req.body.id && user.password === req.body.password) {
                req.session.user = user; //*** PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE ***
                res.redirect('/protected_page'); //*** OR HERE ***
            }
        });
        res.render('login', {message: "Invalid credentials"});
    }
})

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function(){
        console.log("user logged out")
    });
    res.redirect('/login');
})

app.use('/protected_page', function(err,req,res,next){
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

I see that others have asked similar questions, but none of those cases seem to apply to my situation as in those other cases I can see where the code tries to write to the header after sending a response, but in my case I don't see where that's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the conditional logic. If the following condition

```
if (user.id === req.body.id && user.password === req.body.password)
```

is met, both the lines

```
res.redirect('/protected_page');
```

and

```
res.render('login', {message: "Invalid credentials"});
```

will be executed, which is setting the response header again after sent.

Simple Solution:- Put an else condition.

```
       if (user.id === req.body.id && user.password === req.body.password) {
            req.session.user = user; //*** PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE ***
            res.redirect('/protected_page'); //*** OR HERE ***
        }
        else {
            res.render('login', {message: "Invalid credentials"});
        }
```

**NOTE:-** Your signup code also have this problem. Try sending same user.id in the next request.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a closer look at your `/login` route, there are the following lines:

```
users.filter(function(user){
    if (user.id === req.body.id && user.password === req.body.password) {
        req.session.user = user; //*** PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE ***
        res.redirect('/protected_page'); //*** OR HERE ***
    }
});
res.render('login', {message: "Invalid credentials"});
```

As you've already identified, the problem is in one of the both lines within the `if` statement, and you're right: The problem is the second line (the one with the `redirect`).

The reason for this is: A redirect sets the `location` header, the status code (`301`, `302` or `307`), sends those to the client and closes the connection. Unfortunately, you don't exit your function here, since you don't have something such as `return` here.

This means that execution continues, and the call to `res.render` takes place, which tries to set some headers and render a page – which does not work, since the connection has already been closed. Depending on async stuff, it might also happen the other way round (I didn't follow up closely enough to check which one comes first). However, this is where your problems arise from: You try to run `res.render` and `res.redirect`, and both set headers, and both close your connection.

Apart from that you are using the `filter` function of arrays in a strange way, since it *returns* something, so you should rather do:

```
if (!req.body.id || !req.body.password) {
  res.render('login', {message: "Please enter both id and password!"});
  return;
}

const isLoginCorrect = users.some(function (user) {
  return user.id === req.body.id && user.password === req.body.password;
});

if (isLoginCorrect) {
  req.session.user = user;
  res.redirect('/protected_page');
  return;
}

res.render('login', {message: "Invalid credentials"});
```

Since you are not actually interested in the filtered list of users, it may be a better idea to just use `some`, which only returns `true` or `false`, depending on whether an item has been found in the array that matches the given predicate function. Then you can check for this boolean value, and decide how to go on.

Comment: Thank you. You're absolutely right about the `filter` usage. (Just for the record, this wasn't my code -- it was from a tutorial:). Interestingly, adding `return` didn't fix the problem (I guess it's an `async` issue?). To avoid the error, I needed to go with the `if () {} else {}` construct as in the other two answers, but you're analysis of the problem was absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: "Shh, it's a secret!"}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

var users = [
    {
        id : "1",
        password : "1"
    }
];

app.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('signup');
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.id || !req.body.password) {
        res.status(400);
        res.send("Invalid details!");
    } else {
        users.filter(function(user) {
            if (user.id === req.body.id) {
                res.render('signup', {
                    message: "User Already Exists! Login or choose another user id"});
            } 
        });
    var newUser = {id: req.body.id, password: req.body.password};
    users.push(newUser);
    req.session.user = newUser;
    res.redirect('/protected_page');
    }
});

function checkSignIn(req,res, next){
    if (req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        var err = new Error("Not logged in!");
        next(err);
    }
}

app.get('/protected_page', checkSignIn, function(req, res){
    res.render('protected_page',{id: req.session.user.id});
})

app.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login');
})

app.post('/login', function(req,res){
    if (!req.body.id || !req.body.password) {
        res.render('login', {message: "Please enter both id and password!"});
    } else {
        users.filter(function(user){
            if (user.id === req.body.id && user.password === req.body.password) {
                req.session.user = user; //*** PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE ***
                res.redirect('/protected_page'); //*** OR HERE ***
            }
            else {
                res.render('login', {message: "Invalid credentials"});
            }
        });
    }
})

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function(){
        console.log("user logged out")
    });
    res.redirect('/login');
})

app.use('/protected_page', function(err,req,res,next){
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Comment: Pure code with no explanation at all is not very useful to all the other readers here.  People have to try to reverse engineer what you changed and why it fixes the problem.  Not the best kind of answer whether the code is correct or not.